# Having trouble downcasting in c++

Tags: c++

I am iterating through a list of `Animal` objects (which contains 3 or 4 different types of objects all subclassing from `Animal`):

```
foreach (Animal entry, animalList)
{

    switch(entry.animalType)
    {
    case Animal::tiger:
        qDebug() << static_cast<Tiger>(entry).tigerString;
        break;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

`no matching function for call to 'Tiger::Tiger(Animal&)'`

So I tried:

`static_cast<Tiger*>(entry).tigerString;`

Which gives me the following error:

`invalid static_cast from type 'Animal' to type 'Tiger*'`

So finally I decided to change `entry` to a pointer type like so:

`foreach (Animal* entry, animalList)` etc....

And I get the following error:

`cannot convert 'const value_type {aka const Animal}' to 'Animal*' in initialization`

Am I missing something here? I absolutely need to get `tigerString` which is a string specific to the subclass `Tiger`.

What should I be doing?

**UPDATE**
Please see the following (the code has been stripped for cleanliness):

```
std::list<Animal*> animalList;

Tiger *myTiger = new Tiger();
myTiger->animalType= Animal::tiger;
myTiger->tigerString= "I am a tiger";

animalList.push_back(myTiger, animalList);

foreach (Animal* entry, animalList)
{
    Tiger* tiger = dynamic_cast <Tiger*> (entry);

    if (tiger)
    {
        // It is a tiger
    }
    else
    {
        // it is NOT a tiger
     }
}
```

I get the following error at the first line in the `foreach loop`:

`cannot dynamic_cast 'animal' (of type 'class Animal*') to type 'class Tiger*' (source type is not polymorphic)`

Comment: static_cast<Tiger*>(&entry)->tigerString ?

Comment: Be careful, if you are passing `entry` by value, it will _never_ be anything else than a plain `Animal`.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Got the code to compile and run but it crashes my app.

Comment: @Nbr44 it won't make a difference if they really have  list of `Animal` objects.

Comment: why static_cast used, not dynamic_cast for downcasting?

Comment: @Sergey:  Because the code is wrong.

Comment: `foreach`??? What's that, a macro?

Comment: In addition to the slicing and pass-by-value issues already noted, perhaps your `Animal` is (was) actually an `Alligator`, not a `Tiger`...

Comment: @John Dibling Yes the code is indeed wrong and I was not able to compile. This is why I need help

Comment: What is this `foreach` you are using?  That doesn't look like `std::foreach`. In general, that doesn't look like actual C++ code.  Post *actual code* when you cannot get something to compile.  Delete parts of that *actual code* that are not important, until you have a code sample that is short, self contained, and gets exactly the error you are confused about when you compile it.  http://sscce.org

Comment: @PaulG:  And that is why I am trying to help you. :)

Comment: May I suggest you add add a pure virtual function to the base class called "AnimalString()" or some such and then each derived type returns its own string? Then you won't even need the casting and can just loop through the base types and call AnimalString() on them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function takes an `Animal` by-value, rather than by-reference or pointer.  I'm guessing you have a polymorphic hierarchy designed where `Animal` is the ABC and `Tiger` is a concrete derived class.

If so, this code is certianly wrong.  By taking the `Animal` by value, you [slice the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c), and all you're left with is just an `Animal`.  All the `Tiger`ness is gone.

When you did

```
static_cast<Tiger*>(entry).tigerString;
```

You were trying to cast a non-pointer to a pointer.  That will never work.  Change your function to take a `Animal` by reference (or pointer).

You are also trying to use the wrong cast.  You should be using `dynamic_cast`, not `static_cast` here, when going from a base to a derived polymorphic object.

Do this:

```
foreach (Animal* animal)
{
  Tiger* tiger = dynamic_cast <Tiger*> (animal);
  if (tiger)
  {
    // It is a tiger
  }
  else
  {
    // it is NOT a tiger
  }
}
```

Finally, from the comments it was discovered that you were not actually using polymorphic types.  A **polymorphic class** is one which has at least one `virtual` member function in the base class.  One of those `virtual` member functions should be the destructor in most cases<sup>1</sup>:

```
class Animal
{
public:
  virtual ~Animal(){};
};
```

...Even if it is trivial (no implementation).  In many cases this might even be the *only* `virtual` member function, and that's fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> **"One of those `virtual` member functions should be the destructor in most cases"** : This is needed when you will delete an instantiation of the derived class via a pointer to the base class, as with:

```
class Animal
{
public:
  virtual ~Animal() {}
};

class Tiger : public Animal
{
};

int main()
{
  Animal* a = new Tiger;
  delete a; // Without the virtual destructor, this would evoke Undefined Behavior
}
```

Rule Of Thumb:  When in doubt, add a `virtual` destructor to all polymorphic base classes.

Comment: OP claims they have a list of `Animal` objects (they could be wrong, of course). If that is true then passing by reference isn't going to give them much joy.

Comment: @juanchopanza:  Um, yeah you're probably right.  But there is *sooo* much going wrong here, and I had to start somewhere.

Comment: @PaulG:  The compiler error tells you *exactly* what the problem is:  "cannot dynamic_cast 'animal' (of type 'class Animal*') to type 'class Tiger*' (**source type is not polymorphic**)"  You need to make `Animal` polymorphic.

Comment: @John Dibling You were absolutely right, just had to add a virtual method to my Animal class, which is weird because the method does nothing and I don't really need a method in my Animal class.

Comment: @PaulG:  Be sure that `Animal` has a `virtual` destructor.  In fact, in many polymorphic hierarchies the only method that is `virtual` is the dtor.  Also, I would strongly suggest checking out our list of recommended books.  You'll probably get a lot of traction from some of them.

Comment: Thanks John, actually c++ was the first language I ever learned to program in, but that was years ago and I've only started using it again recently. I've got some good books at home, maybe a little outdated but the fundamentals are there. I remember it took me a few months to wrap my head around pointers, fond memories. Truth is I'm under heavy time constraints and have little time to go over the material, I'm more of a c# expert than anything else.